# Nvim on WSL: escaping space in g:clipboard.paste['*']?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, os-clipboard, wsl

According to `:h clipboard-wsl` in neovim,

```
For Windows WSL, try this g:clipboard definition:

let g:clipboard = {
    \   'name': 'WslClipboard',
    \   'copy': {
    \      '+': 'clip.exe',
    \      '*': 'clip.exe',
    \    },
    \   'paste': {
    \      '+': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
    \      '*': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
    \   },
    \   'cache_enabled': 0,
    \ }
```

I have my wsl.conf not to append $PATH, so I modified that so pathes in the script will be full path.
My powershell has a space in its path so I'm trying to escape it, but never succeed.

For example,

- Double-quoting the whole path like `'"/mnt/c/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe" ...'` results in 
  `E475: Invalid value for argument cmd: '"/mnt/c/Program' is not executable` error.
- Quoting just the space like `'/mnt/c/Program" "Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe ...'` results in almost same error except `"/mnt/c/Program` is `/mnt/c/Program"`.
- Escaping the space with `\` like `'/mnt/c/Program\ Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe ...'` causes similar error too.

Why does it happen? How can I avoid it?

Comment: This part of neovim source code is quite tricky. You might think (I certainly did) that nvim will execute a shell command, but that's not the case. I forgot exactly what the implementation is, so can't help you on escaping-slashes. But I am using [a shell script](https://git.sr.ht/~enan/dotfiles/tree/464c7411aa82eabb188bd8ef4769f99d8f367ae0/bin/wslyank) to avoid this kind of situation. And invoking pwsh to use clipboard will be unnecessarily time-consuming (try it yourself and see how long it takes to execute a command through a new instance of pwsh). It's far easier to use `paste` directly.

Comment: Here is my `g:clipboard` dictionary: [sourcehut link](https://git.sr.ht/~enan/dotfiles/tree/464c7411aa82eabb188bd8ef4769f99d8f367ae0/.config/nvim/plugin/user/clipboard.vim). And here is the 'wslyank' script: [sourcehut link](https://git.sr.ht/~enan/dotfiles/tree/464c7411aa82eabb188bd8ef4769f99d8f367ae0/bin/wslyank).

Comment: In my environment there is no `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/paste.exe`. How can I get it?

Comment: Good question. I thought it came with Windows by default, but, after searching the internet, apparently not. I don't know how it came in my Windows 11. I didn't install anything. BTW, neovim ships 'win32yank' with it as well. Check in the `bin/` folder. You can use that instead of 'clip.exe' and 'paste.exe'.

Comment: I built neovim by myself so I got win32yank.exe from github. It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Split command by hand, e.g. `'+': ['/full path to/pwsh', '-c', 'args']`
2. Learn how to create symlinks and have no worries ever
3. Drop pwsh as it's too slow. Just anything else will do better.

Comment: I confirmed that first one worked (though I don't know why). But I'll use another mean for speed reason. Thank you!